# $x^3-x+y=0$ and $y^3+x-y=0$ then what will be the value of x and y?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $x^3-x+y=0$ and $y^3+x-y=0$ then what will be the value of x and y?

Answer (score 1):

Adding two equations, we have $x^3+y^3=0\to x^3=-y^3 \to x=-y$ (I suppose that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$).

Now, replacing,

$x^3-x+y=x^3-x-x=0\to x^3-2x=0\to x^3=2x\to x=0$ or $x=\pm\sqrt{2}$ and $y=0$ or $y=\mp\sqrt{2}$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: With $$x=y-y^3$$ we get $$(y-y^3)^3-y+y^3+y=0$$ or $$(y-y^3)^3+y^3=0$$
factorizing we obtain
$$y^3(y^3-2)(y^4-y^2+1)=0$$ Can you proceed now?

Answer (score 0):

Since $$x^3+y^3=0 \implies (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=0 $$

and $x^2-xy+y^2\ne 0$ we have $x=-y$.

So $x^3-2x=0$ so $x=0$ (and $y=0$) or $x=\pm \sqrt{2} $ (and $y=\mp \sqrt{2} $ )